# Detect when Firefox for Android is affected by a textarea bug

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, firefox

### Background

I am creating a jquery mobile widget that enhances a textarea by providing custom control instead and hiding the original textarea off screen. When interacting with the custom controls by entering text, the user actually enters text into textarea.

Certain characters (such as newlines) are required to be placed in particular places in textarea. This is done by listening for the input event, getting the current text in the textarea, checking and adding any newlines and then setting the text in the textarea to be the updated text.

This works fine in Chrome (v39, Windows 7), Firefox (v35, Windows 7) and Chrome for Android (v39, Android 4.4.4).

### The Problem

However when run in Firefox for Android (v35, Android 4.4.4) the text in the textarea after each update is not what it should be. For example if you typed `Th` you get `_T` in the textarea instead of `Th`.

The sample code below demonstrates this problem when you view it in Firefox for Android and enter text into the textarea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#ta').on("input",function(e){
                    var selection = this.selectionEnd;
                    var text = document.getElementById("ta").value + " ";

                    this.selectionStart = 0;
                    this.selectionEnd = text.length - 1;

                    document.getElementById("ta").value = text;
                    this.selectionStart = selection;
                    this.selectionEnd = selection;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="ta"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the link to the [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1123735)

Is there a way to detect a browser that contains this bug so I can just display the non enhanced textarea?

I don't really want to use the User Agent string as people may of modified this, possibly by trying to request the desktop version.

The only other idea that I had was to check the text in the textarea after it was updated was the same that I thought it should be, however this would show enhanced version before bug occurred which would not be ideal.

Comment: Have you tried detecting the browser version?